# Transfer whole row to other sheet

Tags: excel, vba, macros

[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caSE4.jpg)

I am working on a register for my company. I need such script that if I put party code as "15" then that whole row should be place in sheet no 15.

Comment: let's help you a bit here, share your latest code attempt if you don't want your post to be closed soon. This is not write your code site. SO is about  helping users that are facing problems while writing their own code. See here how to ask a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: In post heading you mentioned `whole column`  but in the post you mentioned `whole row` confusing.....

Comment: sorry for that. I excatly want to transfer the whole row, not column.

Comment: I have added screenshot of my sheet. In that I have a column of PARTY CODE. If I enter party code as "2" then that row should be copied to sheet number 2(that is exactly ledger of that party). If i use party code as "3" that should be transfer to the sheet no.3 (ledger of that party".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your screenshot. Use following subs.

Sub 1: Use this sub if sheets are exist with all party name-

```
    Public Sub AddToExistingSheet()
    Dim PartyCode As Long
        PartyCode = InputBox("Enter Party Code:", "Party code input.")

        For Each cel In Range("E3:E" & Range("E3").End(xlDown).Row)
            If cel.Value = PartyCode Then
                cel.EntireRow.Copy
            End If
        Next

        'Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = PartyCode
        Sheets("" & PartyCode & "").Activate
        Rows("3:3").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End Sub
```

Sub 2: Use this sub if you need to create sheet with party name.

```
    Sub AddToNewSheet()
    Dim PartyCode As Long
        PartyCode = InputBox("Enter Party Code:", "Party code input.")

        For Each cel In Range("E3:E" & Range("E3").End(xlDown).Row)
            If cel.Value = PartyCode Then
                cel.EntireRow.Copy
            End If
        Next

        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = PartyCode
        Rows("3:3").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @harun24hr for this great help. i am not so good about scripting so you have to help me for this. It works great but it need some modification such that if party code repeats, it should not create another sheet, but the row with same party code will copied to precreated sheet.